# Both horizontal slider and vertical slider

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to perform **horizontal** and **vertical** scrolling both in a single screen

But Not found any useful resouces

[TwoWay GridView library doesn't work properly. (Horizontal GridView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504040/twoway-gridview-library-doesnt-work-properly-horizontal-gridview)

Comment: do you need gridview to slide both side or any view?

Comment: No I need the view like in which dynamic images can be loaded from  both directions horizontally and vertically simultaneously like in html5